# How to build Apple "Open Source" projects in Xcode 10

Tags: macos, xcode, macos-mojave

I want to compile the [IOSerialFamily](https://opensource.apple.com/source/IOSerialFamily/IOSerialFamily-93.200.2/) kext bundle on my own machine (OSX 10.14.4) using Xcode 10.2. I downloaded the source tarball from [Apple's open source repository](https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/), but even though the project contains a `.xcodeproj` file, it's obviously not set up to compile on a personal machine. The project does not use the public SDK, but instead uses a `macosx.internal` SDK which I assume to be available only to Apple employees.

I switched it to use the installed SDK, but many problems followed. For example, the "internal" SDK's `sys/tty.h` file must contain a full definition of `struct tty`, whereas the public SDK only contains a forward declaration of the struct. I suspect I can patch in [the version from the darwin-xnu kernel](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/0a798f6738bc1db01281fc08ae024145e84df927/bsd/sys/tty.h), but that would only fix one of the many errors. I'm looking for a solution that would help me fix them all simultaneously.

Does anyone have any experience compiling these "Open Source" projects? How can I set up my environment to do this? Do I have to go through and painstakingly hack away at each individual compiler error? Is there somewhere else that I can obtain a working copy of the IOSerialFamily kext source that *will* compile on a machine with the public SDK?